# bacteria forming in reheating of baked potatoes

Tags: food-safety, temperature, potatoes

I understand that if you do not correctly reheat a baked potato bacteria can set in botulism. what is the correct temperature you need to avoid temperature abuse.  Also can you use the baked potato for other uses ie hash brown that need to be reheated

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your statement? As long as the cooked potato is cooled fairly soon after cooking and then reheated reasoably quickly, I don't believe you will have a problem.

Comment: You have to be pretty reckless to induce botulism in non-canned foods stored in the fridge for a few days. See this link: http://preservingfoodathome.com/tag/non-canned-foods/

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate on a quesiton of reheating chicken, but the rules are the same for potatoes and chicken. For the basics of food safety, please read http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info and see the questions linked at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Because potatoes are grown in the soil, they are a natural source of Clostridium botulinum. C. botulinum could grow in a cooked, foil wrapped baked potato that is not maintained at proper temperature because the combination of cooking and foil wrap create an anaerobic condition. C. botulinum requires an anaerobic (oxygen-free) environment in which to grow.
Bottom line: wash your potatoes, don't use foil, cool properly, reheat properly and you'll be fine.